# App icon not showing up despite app running successfully

Tags: java, system-tray, tray

I have a Java Desktop application for which the icon does not shows up  every time it runs. The app might run successfully but the icon won't show up.
I was hinted by my senior that this might be the issue of the library we use. I looked up on Internet and was unable to find anything.
If anyone has any idea how this may be fixed, pls contact.

I want to add new Libraries to test the functioning of it but is unable to find. As of now dorkbox.SystemTray and dorkbox.Util are the two libraries in usage.

Is there any different library to try out or any method.

The following is my code
This is how I've initialized `SystemTray`

```
    public static SystemTray systemTray;
```

This is the code to display `SystemTray`

```
public static void showTray() throws Exception {
    try {
  
    if (systemTray == null) {
     
        System.exit(0);
    }
  
    System.out.println(SystemTray.DEBUG);
    SystemTray.DEBUG=true;
    CacheUtil.clear();
    SystemTray.FORCE_GTK2=true;
    systemTray.setImage("/usr/local/bin/Desklog-Client/nonet.png");
```

Comment: Are you using [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) and [dorkbox/SystemTray](https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray)?

Comment: dorkbox/SystemTray  ? You meant the library right. Yes I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

A full, working example (also used for validation and testing) is available here: https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray/blob/master/test/dorkbox/TestTray.java

I have also in-lined the source of that file, in case it ever disappears.

```
    /*
     * Copyright 2021 dorkbox, llc
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */
    package dorkbox;
    
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    import dorkbox.os.OS;
    import dorkbox.systemTray.Checkbox;
    import dorkbox.systemTray.Menu;
    import dorkbox.systemTray.MenuItem;
    import dorkbox.systemTray.Separator;
    import dorkbox.systemTray.SystemTray;
    import dorkbox.util.CacheUtil;
    import dorkbox.util.Desktop;
    
    /**
     * Icons from 'SJJB Icons', public domain/CC0 icon set
     */
    public
    class TestTray {
    
        public static final URL BLUE_CAMPING = TestTray.class.getResource("accommodation_camping.glow.0092DA.32.png");
        public static final URL BLACK_FIRE = TestTray.class.getResource("amenity_firestation.p.000000.32.png");
    
        public static final URL BLACK_MAIL = TestTray.class.getResource("amenity_post_box.p.000000.32.png");
        public static final URL GREEN_MAIL = TestTray.class.getResource("amenity_post_box.p.39AC39.32.png");
    
        public static final URL BLACK_BUS = TestTray.class.getResource("transport_bus_station.p.000000.32.png");
        public static final URL LT_GRAY_BUS = TestTray.class.getResource("transport_bus_station.p.999999.32.png");
    
        public static final URL BLACK_TRAIN = TestTray.class.getResource("transport_train_station.p.000000.32.png");
        public static final URL GREEN_TRAIN = TestTray.class.getResource("transport_train_station.p.39AC39.32.png");
        public static final URL LT_GRAY_TRAIN = TestTray.class.getResource("transport_train_station.p.666666.32.png");
    
        // from issue 123
        public static final URL NOTIFY_IMAGE = TestTray.class.getResource("RemoteNotifications.png");
    
        public static
        void main(String[] args) {
            // make sure JNA jar is on the classpath!
            new TestTray();
        }
    
        private final SystemTray systemTray;
        private final ActionListener callbackGray;
    
        public
        TestTray() {
            SystemTray.DEBUG = true; // for test apps, we always want to run in debug mode
    //        SystemTray.FORCE_TRAY_TYPE = SystemTray.TrayType.Swing;
    
            // for test apps, make sure the cache is always reset. These are the ones used, and you should never do this in production.
            CacheUtil.clear("SysTrayExample");
    
            // SwingUtil.setLookAndFeel(null); // set Native L&F (this is the System L&F instead of CrossPlatform L&F)
            // SystemTray.SWING_UI = new CustomSwingUI();
    
            this.systemTray = SystemTray.get("SysTrayExample");
            if (systemTray == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load SystemTray!");
            }
    
            // SWT/JavaFX "shutdown hooks" have changed. Since it's no longer available with JPMS, it is no longer supported.
            // Developers must add the shutdown hooks themselves.
    
            systemTray.setTooltip("Mail Checker");
            systemTray.setImage(LT_GRAY_TRAIN);
            systemTray.setStatus("No Mail");
    
            callbackGray = e->{
                final MenuItem entry = (MenuItem) e.getSource();
                systemTray.setStatus(null)
                          .setImage(BLACK_TRAIN);
    
                entry.setCallback(null);
    //                systemTray.setStatus("Mail Empty");
                systemTray.getMenu().remove(entry);
                entry.remove();
                System.err.println("POW");
            };
    
    
            Menu mainMenu = systemTray.getMenu();
    
            MenuItem greenEntry = new MenuItem("Green Mail", e->{
                final MenuItem entry = (MenuItem) e.getSource();
                systemTray.setStatus("Some Mail!");
                systemTray.setImage(GREEN_TRAIN);
    
                entry.setCallback(callbackGray);
                entry.setImage(BLACK_MAIL);
                entry.setText("Delete Mail");
                entry.setTooltip(null); // remove the tooltip
    //                systemTray.remove(menuEntry);
            });
            greenEntry.setImage(GREEN_MAIL);
            // case does not matter
            greenEntry.setShortcut('G');
            greenEntry.setTooltip("This means you have green mail!");
            mainMenu.add(greenEntry);
    
    
            Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox("Euro € Mail", e->System.err.println("Am i checked? " + ((Checkbox) e.getSource()).getChecked()));
            checkbox.setShortcut('€');
            mainMenu.add(checkbox);
    
            MenuItem removeTest = new MenuItem("This should not be here", e->{
                try {
                    Desktop.browseURL("https://git.dorkbox.com/dorkbox/SystemTray");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            mainMenu.add(removeTest);
            mainMenu.remove(removeTest);
    
            mainMenu.add(new Separator());
    
            mainMenu.add(new MenuItem("About", e->{
                try {
                    Desktop.browseURL("https://git.dorkbox.com/dorkbox/SystemTray");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
    
    
            mainMenu.add(new MenuItem("Temp Directory", e->{
                try {
                    Desktop.browseDirectory(OS.TEMP_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
    
            mainMenu.add(new MenuItem("Notify", e->{
                final MenuItem entry = (MenuItem) e.getSource();
                systemTray.setStatus("Notification!");
                systemTray.setImage(NOTIFY_IMAGE);
    
                entry.setImage(NOTIFY_IMAGE);
                entry.setText("Did notify");
                System.err.println("NOTIFICATION!");
            }));
    
    
            Menu submenu = new Menu("Options", BLUE_CAMPING);
            submenu.setShortcut('t');
    
    
            MenuItem disableMenu = new MenuItem("Disable menu", BLACK_BUS, e->{
                MenuItem source = (MenuItem) e.getSource();
                source.getParent().setEnabled(false);
            });
            submenu.add(disableMenu);
    
    
            submenu.add(new MenuItem("Hide tray", LT_GRAY_BUS, e->systemTray.setEnabled(false)));
            submenu.add(new MenuItem("Remove menu", BLACK_FIRE, e->{
                MenuItem source = (MenuItem) e.getSource();
                source.getParent().remove();
            }));
    
            submenu.add(new MenuItem("Add new entry to tray",
                                     e->systemTray.getMenu().add(new MenuItem("Random " + new Random().nextInt(10)))));
            mainMenu.add(submenu);
    
            MenuItem entry = new MenuItem("Type: " + systemTray.getType().toString());
            entry.setEnabled(false);
            systemTray.getMenu().add(entry);
    
            systemTray.getMenu().add(new MenuItem("Quit", e->{
                systemTray.shutdown();
                //System.exit(0);  not necessary if all non-daemon threads have stopped.
            })).setShortcut('q'); // case does not matter
        }
    }
```